# Boost atomic: wait-free ring buffer with large amount of data

Tags: c++, boost, atomic, circular-buffer

I want to use `boost::atomic` for a wait-free ring buffer as described here:

[Boost Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_ringbuffer)

My `producer` provides large amount of data at the same time (unsigned char, +- 3000 values), just like a matrix it would fill line by line. What is the best way to `push` these values in the buffer ? Should I just loop over them or can I `memcpy` them inside somehow?

Same goes for `pop` if I want to read a bunch of values at the same time...

---

Here is what I came up with, any reason this should not be good ?
I just need to make sure `RINGBUFFERSIZE % iSize = 0`.

```
#define RINGBUFFERSIZE = 30000

ring_[RINGBUFFERSIZE];

bool push(unsigned char* iData, int iSize)
{
    size_t head = head_.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);
    size_t next_head = next(head,iSize);
    if (next_head == tail_.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
    return false;
    memcpy(ring_+head,iData,iSize);
    head_.store(next_head, boost::memory_order_release);
}

bool pop(unsigned char * value, int iSize)
{
     size_t tail = tail_.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);
     if (tail == head_.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
         return false;
     value = &ring_[tail];
     tail_.store(next(tail,iSize), boost::memory_order_release);
     return true;
}


size_t next(size_t current, int iSize)
{
     return (current + iSize) % RINGBUFFERSIZE;
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution doesn't quite work, because `next_head` could have wrapped round. In that case, you don't have a contiguous block and can't do a single `memcpy` (of course you can check for this case and maybe do two).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to push a pointer (either `unsigned char *` or pointer to some structure which contains the length as well).

Of course, assuming it's ok to force `pop` to take exactly the same chunks that were pushed, this just moves the problem: now you have to manage the allocation of these buffers somehow.

---

Simple sample solution for managing your chunks:

1. pre-allocate "enough" fixed-size chunk objects (say a dynamic length + `unsigned char data[3096]` or whatever)
2. send address of a chunk in your wait-free ring buffer
3. send address *back* in another ring buffer when the consumer is done with it, so the producer can recycle the same chunk object

---

If you really can't do this, you *could* pick a maximum size for your chunks and push/pop objects of that size by value ... but honestly this seems very wasteful (even if object knows its length so doesn't have to `memcpy` the whole 3k array for smaller chunks).

Comment: Exactly, the memory pointed to won't be valid anymore, so I need to copy the data itself.

Comment: Surely you control the validity of your buffers?

Comment: The data comes from a tcp connection, so I need to store it every read.

Comment: Yeah, but the allocation and lifetime management of the memory you read into is under your control ... unless your concern is specifically reassembling partial reads?

Comment: You can certainly do that, but I don't think it will be easy to do with this container (which is oriented towards discrete value objects rather than streams of variable-length data)

Comment: Hence the question posted here on SO ;), but thanks for the help so far. +1

Comment: Perhaps you could edit some more information on what your data looks like, and how you parse/consume it, into your question?